# Transforming table to longtable error

Tags: tables, longtable

I have been trying to convert the following table into a longtable, so it will extend on to multiple pages, since it's too long for a single page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry} 

 \usepackage{makecell,multirow}
 \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
 \usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{c|}}
    \hline
\thead{Probe Type}  &  \thead{Repeats Compared} & \thead{KS and p Values} \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrophobic} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.56 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.008 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{1-3}          
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrogen Bond Acceptor} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.67 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.007 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.80 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.88 \\
\cline{1-3}           
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrogen Bond Donor} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.42 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.04 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.99 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.54 \\
\cline{1-3}           
\multirow{6}{*}{Polar} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.69 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.008 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.70 \\
\cline{1-3}                    
\multirow{6}{*}{Positive Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.47 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.004 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.99 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{1-3}                  
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

according to previous answers on stackexchange and by using:

```
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{c|}}
```

and omitting the centering and the caption line. However, I still get errors. Any suggestions on how to convert it?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! in your documentexample are missed packages `makecell` and `multirow`. `longtable` had not to be inside float environment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `table` environment and insert the caption inside the `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable,multirow,makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{c|}}
\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}\\
\hline
\thead{Probe Type}  &  \thead{Repeats Compared} & \thead{KS and p Values} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\thead{Probe Type}  &  \thead{Repeats Compared} & \thead{KS and p Values} \\
\hline
\endhead
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrophobic} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.56 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.008 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\hline          
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrogen Bond Acceptor} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.67 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.007 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.80 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.88 \\
\hline           
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrogen Bond Donor} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.42 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.04 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.99 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.54 \\
\hline           
\multirow{6}{*}{Polar} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.69 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.008 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.70 \\
\hline                    
\multirow{6}{*}{Positive Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.47 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.004 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.99 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\hline                  
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\pagebreak
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Since you have `\multirow` commands, you have to manually check page breaks and insert `\pagebreak` where necessary, as shown in the example

[image]

On the other hand, I'd suggest a different realization: jailed tables are so bad! Also repeating KS or p in all rows is a waste of space: you can save it and make a four column table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lcS[table-format=1.3]S[table-format=1.2]}
\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}\\
\toprule
Probe Type  &  Repeats Compared & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Values} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
            &                   & {KS} & {p} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Probe Type  &  Repeats Compared & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Values} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-4}
            &                   & {KS} & {p} \\
\midrule
\endhead
Hydrophobic
& 1st - 2nd & 0.01  & 0.56 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.01  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.008 & 0.58 \\
\midrule
Hydrogen Bond Acceptor
& 1st - 2nd & 0.02  & 0.67 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.007 & 0.80 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.01  & 0.88 \\
\midrule
Hydrogen Bond Donor
& 1st - 2nd & 0.01  & 0.42 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.04  & 0.99 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.01  & 0.54 \\
\midrule
Polar
& 1st - 2nd & 0.02  & 0.69 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.008 & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.02  & 0.70 \\
\midrule
Positive Charge
& 1st - 2nd & 0.01  & 0.47 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.004 & 0.99 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.01  & 0.58 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 1
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 2
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 3
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 4
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 5
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 6
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
\pagebreak
Negative Charge 7
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 8
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 9
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 10
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 11
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 12
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\midrule
Negative Charge 13
& 1st - 2nd & 0.08  & 0.58 \\
& 1st - 3rd & 0.08  & 0.49 \\
& 2nd - 3rd & 0.07  & 0.73 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for making a difference between first head and head in this example?

Comment: @TeXnician The first head contains the caption; depending on tastes, it need not be repeated.

Comment: Thank you very much! This, and the \pagebreak tip, seems to do exactly what I want it to do!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to load the `longtable` package (and as you use `\multirow` you need that package too). Furthermore `longtable` has a different way of specifying the caption (apart from not being allowed within a float) and the `makecell` approach for the table head will not work as expected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{c|}}
    \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}\\
    \hline
Probe Type  &  Repeats Compared & KS and p Values \\
\hline\endhead
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrophobic} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.56 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.008 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{1-3}          
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrogen Bond Acceptor} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.67 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.007 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.80 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.88 \\
\cline{1-3}           
\multirow{6}{*}{Hydrogen Bond Donor} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.42 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.04 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.99 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.54 \\
\cline{1-3}           
\multirow{6}{*}{Polar} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.69 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.008 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.02 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.70 \\
\cline{1-3}                    
\multirow{6}{*}{Positive Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.47 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.004 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.99 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.01 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{1-3}                  
\multirow{6}{*}{Negative Charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 2nd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.58 \\
\cline{2-3}                & \multirow{2}{*}{1st - 3rd} & KS = 0.08 \\
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.49 \\
\cline{2-3}                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2nd - 3rd} & KS = 0.07 \\  
\cline{3-3}                 &       & p = 0.73 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It does work, however the splitting of the table is a bit "bad" with certain rows being placed under the page number or being hidden between two pages. Are there any options to split it in a more aesthetically pleasing way?

Comment: @kapoios_kanateris You can influence splitting by using `\\*` instead of `\\` to prevent breaking at that point. But everything else seems very subjective (aesthetics).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, with a simpler code. I removed part of the `\cline`s for aesthetic reasons, and used `\makecell` in the place of `\multirow`. Don't forget that in a longtable, the caption is part of the environment, in the `\endfirsthead` section:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm, vmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, longtable}

\begin{document}

{ \setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells%
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{c|}}
\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel} \\
\hline
\thead{Probe Type} & \thead{Repeats Compared} & \thead{KS and p Values} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\thead{Probe Type} & \thead{Repeats Compared} & \thead{KS and p Values} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape To be continued on next page}
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
& 1st - 2nd & \makecell{KS = 0.01 \\p = 0.56 } \\ \cline{2-3}
Hydrophobic &{1st - 3rd} & \makecell{KS = 0.01 \\ p = 0.49} \\ \cline{2-3}
& 2nd - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.008 \\ p = 0.58} \\
\hline
& 1st - 2nd & \makecell{KS = 0.02 \\ p = 0.67} \\ \cline{2-3}
\makecell{Hydrogen Bond\\ Acceptor} & 1st - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.007 \\ p = 0.80} \\ \cline{2-3}
& 2nd - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.01 \\ p = 0.88} \\
\hline
& 1st - 2nd & \makecell{KS = 0.01 \\ p = 0.42} \\ \cline{2-3}
\makecell{Hydrogen Bond\\ Donor} & 1st - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.04 \\ p = 0.99} \\ \cline{2-3}
& 2nd - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.01 \\ p = 0.54} \\
\hline
& 1st - 2nd & \makecell{KS = 0.02 \\ p = 0.69} \\ \cline{2-3}
Polar & 1st - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.008 \\ p = 0.49} \\ \cline{2-3}
& 2nd - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.02 \\ p = 0.70} \\
\hline
& 1st - 2nd & \makecell{KS = 0.01 \\ p = 0.47} \\ \cline{2-3}
Positive Charge & 1st - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.004 \\ p = 0.99} \\ \cline{2-3}
& 2nd - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.01 \\ p = 0.58} \\
\hline
& 1st - 2nd & \makecell{ KS = 0.08 \\ p = 0.58} \\ \cline{2-3}
Negative Charge & 1st - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.08 \\ p = 0.49} \\ \cline{2-3}
& 2nd - 3rd & \makecell{KS = 0.07 \\ p = 0.73}
\end{longtable}
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]